# Do kashrut agencies inspect pickling spices for insects before adding them to brined meat?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat, bugs, inspection

I noticed that pickled meats such as corned beef, pastrami and tongue are covered with seeds twigs and leaves. (Most of it seems to be allspice.)

Considering that kashrut agencies have been so concerned about inspecting all types of produce, I'm curious if the various spices that they use had been checked before adding them to the meat. If such spices do not need to be inspected before this process, or at all, please provide a source to explain this.

Answer (score 3):

[See this list of "dried spices that are acceptable for kosher use without specific Kosher supervision"](http://www.crcweb.org/spice_list.php) - Allspice is literally the first entry. Many spices are considered to not require supervision when by themselves. Blends require either supervision or a thorough spec sheet to ensure that the blend only contains spices (some blends use flavorants, sugars, and the like).

So the majority of spices used in pickling don't require checking. If the pickling plant has supervision itself inspecting the production of pastrami, perhaps particular precision pertaining to the provision of piquancy is not compulsory.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't resist the alliteration once I got started... :D